# Why my media query code is not working in CSS?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

Problem:- I have applied media query but it is not working . My paragraph keeps on going out of mobile's screen width and not only that I ended up having a long vertical row of nothing and the same goes for horizontal row.
And the aqua color div is at the extreme right side

My Thought(I think since I am brand new to the concept of media query I am 99% sure I have typed media query code all wrong :"|)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 90.5vh;
}

.left {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.left h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-size: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left h6 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left p {
  font-size: 18px;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img_part {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.img_part img {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 220px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.last {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 750px;
  top: -320px;
  z-index: -999;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* // Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) */

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .left p {
    font-size: 15px;
    word-spacing: 0.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    width: auto;
  }
}


/* // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */

@media (min-width: 768px) {}


/* // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */

@media (min-width: 992px) {}


/* // X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {}


/* // XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up) */

@media (min-width: 1400px) {}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xxl-6 collg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mx-auto left">
        <h1>DETAILS</h1>
        <h6>summer collection</h6>
        <p>Vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque. Consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo in vitae. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. Molestie ac feugiat sed lectus
          vestibulum mattis.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Learn More</a>

      </div>
      <div class="col-xxl-6 collg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mx-auto img_part">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500" alt="image" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</section>
```

Website I am currently working on:
https://ibb.co/ScjxMT5

Problem that I am facing:-
https://ibb.co/fXXMtV0

As you can clearly see that my paragraph goes out of the mobile's width screen even as low as 400px

I have already made sure that my window current size is 100%.

Comment: Last one, 1400, is missing a px

Comment: it is still not working even after including the missing one

Answer (score 3):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .yourclassname or #yourid {
    /* styling... */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using the media query for the entire screen width you have to add "only screen and"

So

```
 @media only screen and (min-width:1000px){....}
```